# How to click a button to enable a menu item in google docs using chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-docs

I wanted to build an extension for chrome which will do various work on google docs. But before that, I want to make sure that I'm having access to all the features in a google doc. So, I coded this to enable a click event on a google doc to enable "Bold". but somehow, it is not working at all. it never triggers, even though I click multiple times on my extension.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var Boldbtn = document.getElementById('Boldbtn');
    
    Boldbtn.onclick = function(){
        console.log("button  clicked");
    };
};
```

In this code, I'm just printing a message by using a button. Please, share your experience, where did I do wrong, and what will be the best practice to resolve this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this part of content.js? Also try to console log Boldbtn to see if it is not undefined.

Comment: Yes. It is in the content-scrip.js

Comment: Did the `console.log(Boldbtn)` print the DOM element?

Comment: I did but it didn't show any message or error at all.

Comment: I just checked the **id** of the bold button and it shows up to me as "boldButton" not "Boldbtn" - confirm if this is the issue here. Also, can you expand a little on what you are trying to do? There may be easier ways to do what you want i.e. Apps Script or Add-ons. Let me know if you want more info.

Comment: My plan is this: I'll control some button of google doc using chrome extension. 'Boldbtn' is the id of a button of the extension. Is there any way i can access or control them from the extension?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that the title reflects the content of the question and answer? it looks more like monitoring a button than grammatically clicking it to me.

Answer (score 0):

## Inline JavaScript is not allowed by Google, use `addEventListener`

Google does not permit Inline JavaScript so you need to `addEventListener` for the button press to register, *not* modfying the element attribute `onClick`:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  function myFunction() {
    console.log("button clicked");
  }
  
  document.getElementById("boldButton").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
}
```

While testing I also found it was reliable to include in the manifest:

```json
"content_scripts": ["run-at": "document_end"]
```

*Notes*:

- This example is in a content script and logs to console every time a user presses the "bold" button on the Google Docs toolbar.
- The inclusion of "run-at" in the manifest just prevents anything from being overwritten while Google Docs is starting up.
- If you are wanting to format the content of the document you will probably be better off looking at Google Docs Add Ons, or the Docs API. There you will find easier, faster and more reliable methods for editing operations. You can also make calls to the Docs API from your within your extension if you want. (but you may be thinking of something else entirely so maybe this is not useful)

*References*:

[Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy)
[addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
[Docs API](https://developers.google.com/docs/api)

Comment: In what way is this programmatically clicking a button? Maybe the question title needs to be changed.

Comment: Maybe so, as the question is about enabling the bold button in Google docs via a custom button in a chrome extension, not about programmatically clicking as such. At least that is what I understood.